# Unsure about parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a beginner's MVC tutorial. I was wondering if anyone could explain how or where the parameters of this method are chosen?

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);
    return View(album);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the `id` parameter? Can you post the code that calls the `Details` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways your id parameter could be populated:

```
 http://www.example.com/{Controller}/Details/{id}
```

or

```
 http://www.example.com/{Controller}/Details?id={id}
```

where {Controller} is the name of your Controller, eg. The name of HomeController.cs would be "Home"
and where {id} is an int.

Answer (score 0):

you're working with the default route I guess, so you gonna find in the Global.asax file the follow code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
```

your route is that! where "id" is a optional parameter, suppose that your controller name is Album, so test `http://mySite/Album/Details/10`

you get a request where 10 is your Id parameter specify on the action Details